# "As is customary" vs. "as it is customary"

Tags: grammaticality, subjects, dummy-it

I more often see the first version being used, but to me, that doesn't sound right because I can't see the subject there. I would definitely use the second one.

What am I missing here?

**Update:** searching "As is customary" on Google returns more results than "As it is customary", hinting the first form is the most widely used... but I don't know whether that is a good test.

Answer (score 9):

Actually, it's not possible to answer this question in its present form because there is no context.

**As is customary** is used in one type of sentence,

and

**As it is customary** is used in two other types of sentences.

Without full sentences, there's no telling what the second phrase means. Let me illustrate in these sentences about military funerals:

> ***As is customary**, someone played Taps, and seven enlisted men gave the dead soldier a twenty-one gun salute.*  This is merely a description of what happened.

versus

> ***As it is customary**, someone played Taps, and seven enlisted men gave the dead soldier a twenty-one gun salute.* This explains why what happened happened and gives a reason for what happened; "as" means "because" in this sentence but not in the previous sentence.

versus

> ***As it is customary to do**, someone played Taps, and seven enlisted men gave the dead soldier a twenty-one gun salute.* This explains why what happened happened (which may be construed as a reason, I suppose), but "as" doesn't mean "because" in this sentence. It is an unelided version of the first sentence.

versus

> ***Because it is customary to do this**, someone played Taps, and seven enlisted men gave the dead soldier a twenty-one gun salute.* This explains why what happened happened  and gives a reason for what happened; "as" means "because" in this sentence. It is an unelided version of the third sentence.

All four are grammatically and semantically correct, but the second sentence is different because it uses this ambiguous little two-letter word that so many native speakers of English don't mind using to confuse readers and listeners. This should demonstrate quite clearly that there is no "dummy *it*" needed and that the first is **not** an elided version of the second.

Comment: Hi Bill. Good explanantion, thanks. There is still something I don't understand. In the sentence "As is customary, someone played Taps", what's the subject for the verb "is"?

Comment: @dan: It's not a complete sentence, it's an expression.

Comment: @Noah: I thought with a verb, a sentence is a full sentence. I thought even a verb alone is a full sentence (e.g.: "Play!"). Is maybe "As" the subject? I am confused...this is one of the times, not being a native speaker takes its toll :-(

Comment: @dan: Good question. There is no subject because, as Noah pointed out, it's not a complete sentence. "As" is an adverb and not the subject of "is", and the phrase is idiomatic. John Lawler will be able to explain the grammar of that phrase, as might a few other of the big guns here -- Andrew Leach, Barrie England, Colin Fine, just to name three I'm sure know the answer (and there are many others) -- but I can't beyond saying that it's an introductory adverbial phrase.

Comment: FANTASTIC!!!! (+1)

Comment: @dan: Not all verbs can be stand-alone sentences, only ones that can be used as imperatives. "House" can be a verb, but `House.` isn't really a complete sentence. Most sentences have a subject and a verb, although sometimes the subject can be implied (the subject in `Play!`, for instance, is "you" – although it's not stated, it's implied by the context).

Comment: I have heard similar usages in India; e.g., as is the practice... How does it differ from 'as it is the practice'? Both are not dissimilar. Are they different from "as (it is) known to you, as (it is/was) informed, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, 'as is customary' adds context to an action that will be occurring regardless of the accompanying statement, whereas 'as it is customary' explains why the action is happening in the first place.

Here's an example of the first:

> As is customary, Aunt Nina gifted the kids wristwatches for Christmas.

This means:

> **As** she is known to do, Aunt Nina gifted the kids wristwatches for Christmas.

We don't know *why* Aunt Nina's gifting the kids these wristwatches, we just know that she usually does.

Now, for the second:

> As it is customary, Aunt Nina gifted the kids wristwatches for Christmas.

This means:

> **Because** she is known to do it, Aunt Nina gifted the kids wristwatches for Christmas.

Here, we *do* know why Aunt Nina's gifting the kids wristwatches. It's because she usually does and she's expected to again. Hope this makes sense.