# what the phrase/ formula of "as is" means

Tags: phrases

"As is".

I often run into sentences which have this little formula.
Can you please shed some light on the function of it?
As I understand it is basically "as it is", but always have a feeling that I am missing
out on some subtle meaning and/or that there is not a perfect consensus regarding what it
is for - but that's just my guess.

Comment: Can you offer an example of how you hear it used, please?

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90800/as-is-customary-vs-as-it-is-customary

Answer (score 1):

It is not used very frequently, and I would normally use it myself only very casually. It does mean *as it is*, but occurs only in certain contexts. Someone selling a used car, for example, might say 'You'll have to take it as is', meaning that the seller won't be responsible for any faults it may have.